# Prevent jQuery from running mouseenter on touch devices

Tags: jquery, touch

I have written some fancy hover scrolling effects in jQuery.  They work great on a desktop computer.  My problem is that on a mobile device, because the user taps on the screen, my code still believes the user is hovering on my .scrollright div and keeps scrolling.

How can I disable this, or otherwise just prevent this problem, on mobile/tablet devices?

```
$('.thumbnails .scrollright').on('mouseenter', function() {
    this.iid = setInterval(function() {
        var CurrentScrollLeft = $( ".thumbnails .thumbnailphotos" ).scrollLeft();
        $( ".thumbnails .thumbnailphotos" ).scrollLeft( CurrentScrollLeft+10 );         
    }, 50);
    }).on('mouseleave', function(){
        this.iid && clearInterval(this.iid);
    });
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A quick check for touch maybe?

```
var tap = ("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement);
```

Then wrap your code in the condition:

```
if(!tap){
    $('.thumbnails .scrollright').on('mouseenter', function() {
        this.iid = setInterval(function() {
            var CurrentScrollLeft = $( ".thumbnails .thumbnailphotos" ).scrollLeft();
            $( ".thumbnails .thumbnailphotos" ).scrollLeft( CurrentScrollLeft+10 );         
        }, 50);
    }).on('mouseleave', function(){
        this.iid && clearInterval(this.iid);
    });
}
```

Something like that anyways.

Comment: Thanks, Chris, that worked (at least on Android).  Should this method work on iOS and all other major touch devices as well?  I only have Android devices here to test on.

Comment: Hey Chris. Yep, should work across the board. At least when only dealing with mobile devices. This may actually become sticky when you consider devices that honor touch and mouse events. 
`if (window.PointerEvent) { // things to do if pointer object exists }`

Comment: This wouldn't work for a device that has touch AND a mouse. For example, a touch-screen laptop.

Comment: This is not a good answer. 1. touchstart may be defined despite there not being a touch device. 2. There are laptops with touch screens